# Flummoxxed by Text Encoding in Python 3.4: How to Prevent "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode"

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

Once again, problems with handling character encoding have started to haunt me.
I am opening a text file containing XML and importing it to

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import codecs

f = open('Acta_Diabetol_2008_Jun_29_45(2)_107-127.nxml','r',encoding='cp1252')
myTree = ET.parse( f )
f.close()

of = open( 'Acta_Diabetol_2008_Jun_29_45(2)_107-127.txt','w')      
for elem in myTree.iter('sec'):
    of.write( elem2StringRecurse( elem ) )  #gets mad here
of.close()
```

The error given is

```
line 197, in <module>
of.write( elem2StringRecurse( elem ) )
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2265' 
in position 139: character maps to <undefined>
```

My problem is two fold.  First, although an experienced programmer, researching this has been more than normally chaotic because this is handled different in Python 2 and 3.
Thus, I am not sure what the error means.
I know that some Italian " a' " looking character is the culprit.  **Is it telling me that there is no Unicode substitution**?

**Second, how to I prevent this in the general case?**  I am trying to write code to pump and dump text files for natural language processing: from XML --> plain text.  I can't have it crash over something like this; I mean I believe I can manually edit out the offending character, but I can't do it for 1000 occurrences...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
f = open('Acta_Diabetol_2008_Jun_29_45(2)_107-127.nxml', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

and

```
of = open('Acta_Diabetol_2008_Jun_29_45(2)_107-127.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Encoding XML in anything other than UTF-8 is asking for trouble.

Looking at your file (linked in the comments), it's clear that it's encoded in ASCII which is a subset of UTF-8 (and also of cp1252, which is probably why Firefox and jEdit are guessing that it's using that encoding). It also contains several Unicode escapes beyond `0xff` that ElementTree appears to be parsing into Unicode codepoints. If you try to save that back to a cp1252-encoded file, the error that you encountered is the result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was using the 'cp1252' codec, because the file is encoded in that codec.  (Confirmed by Jedit and FireFox).  Is that not the right thing to do?
ALSO --> It works now, thanks.

Comment: Does it say `encoding='cp1252'` within the XML file itself? It's possible, but that encoding doesn't know several characters used in "European" languages. Can you post the file somewhere or give us a link to it?

Comment: Here she is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3RjoEb8jEORalAtYi1zemVXS2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, that file appears to be ASCII-encoded, but it contains a lot of encoded characters like `&#x02019` not included in ASCII or cp1252. ElementTree appears to be parsing those into Unicode code points - causing the writing of the file in the cp1252 encoding to fail. So try opening it as you're doing now and saving it using `utf-8`.

Comment: changing this to f = open('Acta_Diabetol_2008_Jun_29_45(2)_107-127.nxml','r',encoding='utf-8') fixed it and gave no artifacts.  So mystery solved.

Comment: I think what might have been going on is that the file incorrectly reports it is encoding in 'cp1252', when it's really 'utf-8', no wonder I was going crazy.  (NotePad++ also says it's UTF-8)

Comment: No, it's encoded in ASCII which is a subset of UTF-8. Are you saving it as UTF-8?